# How to get full belongs_to object in json render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I have an object that belongs_to :companies, and has the :company_id attribute. When I render json: @coupons, is it possible for the JSON to contain an attribute of its owner rather than the company_id?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be able to do something like `render :json => @coupons.to_json(:include => :company)`, at least it seems to have worked with my initial testing in rails 2.3.8.

*Answer edited to use `:include => :company` rather than `:include => :companies`*

Comment: Does a coupon really belong to :companies (plural) ? if not, try the above but :include => :company

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep your json as compact as possible, it's best to use custom model methods to return only the data you need. I ended up adding a custom `as_json` method to the parent model and using the `methods` option to return subsets of the related object's data. Using `include` will include a full json serialization of the related model.

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(
    :only => [:id, :name],
    :methods => [
      :organization_type_name,
    ]
  )
end

def organization_type_name
  self.organization_type.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your conventions are wrong.

Its should be

// In coupon.rb

```
belongs_to :company
```

And while rendering the object do this

```
render json: @coupon.as_json(include: :company)
```