# Ruby on Rails 5: How to print nested json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I'm learning Ruby on Rails (Specially for API development) and I need some help with something.
Lets say we have 2 tables, "Brands" and "Cars".
What I'm trying to do is basically:

1. Get a car: Instead of displaying "brand_id: x", I want to display "brand = { id: X, name: Y}", just as a nested JSON.
2. Do that for each car.

Now, when I try to reach a car, it brings me:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Veneno",
    "brand_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2016-12-03T21:47:01.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-03T21:47:01.000Z"
  }
```

My files contains the following:
Migration files:

```
class CreateBrands < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :brands do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :brand_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :items, :brand_id
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

Currently, my items_controller.rb is:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    render json: @items
  end

  # GET /items/1
  def show
    render json: @item, :only => [:id, :name]
  end

  # POST /items
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :brand_id)
    end
end
```

Thank you! I'm online 24/7 to provide more info about this issue. I googled it a lot but I couldn't find out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is how you want to **serialize** your model. There are gems that provide high-powered solutions to this problem (the venerable but still-relevant `active_model_serializers`, for example), but for basic use-cases, you can get away with leveraging Rails' surprisingly-powerful [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).

For example, to make your show method include the brand object:

```
class ItemsController
  # GET /items/1
  def show
    render json: @item, :includes => [:brand]
  end
end
```

You can also override the default as_json at the model level, but that solution becomes tricky when different callers want different serializations and levels of detail. See [Include associated model when rendering JSON in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730121/include-associated-model-when-rendering-json-in-rails) for another example similar to what you're describing, but more involved.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've just tried that code but is not working, I get the item with the "brand_id" attribute. Tried with ":includes => [:brand]: and with the [item.as_json(includes: :brand). Maybe its a model/migration file issue?
EDIT: Nevermind, it works now. Thank you!