# Neo4jrb with rails --api: return connected nodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, neo4j.rb

Super simple setup:

- Created a new rails app with `--api` and added the generator/framework
- Created a single model (Artefacts) with a `name` attribute and a `has_many` relationship to other Artefacts (boringly named `.artefacts`)
- Created 2 nodes, and joined them (`node1.artefacts = node2`)

Now, when browsing to `/artefacts`, the JSON returned is just the 2 nodes.

- How can Rails return the relationships
- and for down the road; how can Rails return a custom JSON layout such as:

  `[{"artefact":{"name":"Node1","id":"e6571172-889c-4dd9-abca-a522f28c970d", artefacts: ["0643d8c5-fc67-431c-b015-7c5894439058", "5e7ceb40-18da-474e-8fe0-22d3887943b4"]}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you're serializing.  By default Rails will just serialize the node object.  You should be able to use the `include` option as suggested here for `ActiveRecord`:

[Include associated model when rendering JSON in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730121/include-associated-model-when-rendering-json-in-rails)

I also personally like the [json:api](http://jsonapi.org/) standard for serializing objects.  One of the big advantages is that you can include associated objects and the objects are side-loaded efficiently so that you don't include duplicates in your responses.  The other thing that I like about it is it's a *standard*, whereas when I've rendered JSON in apps in the past it's often been just whatever the developer working on that card thought was best.

The `jsonapi-resources` gem is popular for this:

https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources

That gem takes care a lot of the Rails integration and creates controllers and routes for you, but there are some problems with the integration with `ActiveNode`.  I've used the `jsonapi-serializers` gem with success, but it requires you to do some more things for yourself:

https://github.com/fotinakis/jsonapi-serializers

You might look at this Rails example of it:

https://github.com/fotinakis/jsonapi-serializers#rails-example

Comment: Thanks for the info; I was able to accomplish returning the connected nodes. the jsonapi-resources gem looks compelling for the future uses, but trying to implement it was a quick trip down a steep rabbit hole. Is it worth integrating with Neo4jrb just to follow the JSON:API standard?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but to clarify the jsonapi gems don't just work with the `neo4j` gem but also work (and in the case of `jsonapi-resources` was designed to work with) ActiveRecord.  Really JSON:API doesn't have anything to do with your question, it's just a JSON standard which I've enjoyed using ;)

Comment: What I mean to say is; JSON:API looks like a good direction to pursue, but I had difficulty implementing the gem (too much to learn at once), so my side question is: to get to where I want to be (returning a JSON:API response with connected nodes) is the `jsonapi-resources` gem the right thing to learn?