# Rails API - limit .includes() results to only the latest created record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, sqlite, api, crud

I want to render all objects of a certain class, including the latest associated element when, the index-action of a controller is called.

Here is the code for my chatroom-model. A chatroom can have many subscribers:

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :subscribers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When a user visits the starting page, he should see all chatrooms and the most recently created subscriber for each chatroom (not the most recently associated).

My controller looks like this. It does not work and I'm cofident, that there is a method to somehow limit the `(:include => :subscribers)` command or so:

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
   # GET /chatrooms
   def index
      @chatrooms= Chatroom.all.includes(Subscriber.where("subscriber.created_at < ?", Time.now).order('created_at DESC').first)
      render json: @chatrooms
   end
end
```

I struggle to find a solution on how to select the correct subscriber object. Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: What happens if you have less chatrooms than subscribers, or viceversa? I guess as you want related and non-related subscribers you should manage them in two separate queries.

Comment: No, all subscribers are related to a chatroom object, but i want to render just the most recent one. If there are non for a chatroom, it's ok, but when there are more than one, I have to filter out all but the most recent subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eagerly load the latest **associated** subscriber for each chatroom, you can add `has_one` association with scope to your `Chatroom` model:

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :subscribers, dependent: :destroy
   has_one :latest_subscriber, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Subscriber' 
end
```

And include it:

```
@chatrooms = Chatroom.includes(:latest_subscriber).all
```

> When a user visits the starting page, he should see all chatrooms and
>   the most recently created subscriber (not the most recently
>   associated).

For loading one, the most recently created subscriber, **without association** to particular chatroom, you should use the separate query. For example:

```
@most_recent_subsciber = Subscriber.order(created_at: :desc).first
```

Then just build JSON-response that will consist of chatrooms array to render them separately with ability to also render the latest subscriber ([if you include it in `render json`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17730121/5565348)) for each chatroom, and the most recently created subscriber.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the latest_subscriber association shold work for me. And sorry for the confusion, I meant the most recently created subscriber for each chatroom. So I want to query for each chatroom out of all associated subscribers the one that was created last.

Comment: It does, but can you explain me your syntax? It doesn't work for me and I have never seen such a structure in Rails^^

Comment: @mfaorlkzus Join [the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165760/rails-api-limit-includes-results-to-only-the-latest-created-record).