# Unable to get books in authors, ruby has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I am new to ruby. I have two models `Book` and `Author`. I want to apply the association between tow models. Books belongs to one Author, an author can have more than one books. Here is my model.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :author_id, presence: true
end
```

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true
end
```

When I hit GET: http://localhost:3000/books I am getting this response which is valid.

```
 [
   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name",
        "body": "hai",
        "created_at": "2019-12-07T07:44:07.420Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-07T07:44:07.420Z",
        "author_id": 1
    }
]
```

But when I am hitting http://localhost:3000/authors I am getting this repsonse. Here I am unable to see books info. do I need to add any specific code? or Assosications are isn't just enough?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Miss Mora Bogan",
        "age": "20",
        "created_at": "2019-12-07T06:22:27.251Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-07T06:22:27.251Z"
    },
]
```

Comment: post your `index`  action's code of  `authors_controller`

Comment: and `index` action's code of `books_controller.rb`

Comment: What is your question? What to do to get `/authors` to have the author's books nested returned too? Or how to use the information from `/authors` to load corresponding books from `/books`? And btw how does your controller look like?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to call `index` action in `json` format. (`http://localhost:3000/authors.json`)

You need to include associated model when rendering JSON, so for this authors controller should look like as below:

```
# authors_controller.rb

class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authors = Author.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @authors, include: [:books] }
    end
  end
end
```

refer: [Include associated model when rendering JSON in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730121/include-associated-model-when-rendering-json-in-rails)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to control what your json response looks like, there are many options. [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) is already used in rails and you can do something like

```rb
# app/views/books/index.json.jbuilder

json.array! @books do |book|
  json.name book.name
  json.body book.body
  json.author do
    json.name book.author.name
    json.age  book.author.age
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/authors/index.json.jbuilder

json.array! @authors do |author|
  json.name author.name
  json.age  author.age
  json.books author.books do |book|
    json.name book.name
    json.body book.body
  end
end
```

There are shorter ways to achieve same thing using jbuilder. Checkout [examples and document](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder#jbuilder)

Still you need to correctly do response and format in your controller.

Answer (score -2):

what you're getting in json are simply values of table fields from db. foreign key to author for relation between books and authors is stored in books table, not in both, so to get info about books you need to tell in controller method what to join from books table.