# Bring the user name when query an item in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an endpoint the returns all the comments on a blog. I would like to have the name of the user that made the comment. Is there a way to bring it all together when hitting that `comments` endpoint or do I have to make another query for each comment?

```
  def comments
    @comments = @blog.comments
    render json: { comments: @comments }
  end
```

This is what doing `@blog.comments` returns

```
[#<Comment id: 1, content: "This is a very good post", created_at: "2020-09-11 01:55:56", updated_at: "2020-09-11 01:55:56", blog_id: 3, user_id: 1>, #<Comment id: 2, content: "I agree with all of this", created_at: "2020-09-11 01:55:56", updated_at: "2020-09-11 01:55:56", blog_id: 3, user_id: 1>, #<Comment id: 3, content: "I don't agree with all of this", created_at: "2020-09-11 01:55:56", updated_at: "2020-09-11 01:55:56", blog_id: 3, user_id: 1>]>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include associated model when rendering JSON in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730121/include-associated-model-when-rendering-json-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a users table with a field users.name, and a belongs_to :user relationship on your model comment:

Just replace the line

```
@comments = @blog.comments
```

with

```
@comments = @blog.comments.select('comments.*, users.name').joins(:user)
```